# jQuery | dynamically check checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button

please check at first Jsfiddle: http://tinyurl.com/q58dnpo
this little script works exactly how I imagined. It allows you to check just one checkbox and it dynamically syncs the checkboxes. So far so good.

BUT after pasting it into a more complex script the sync-function just works exactly one time clicking A,B and C. 
check it out here: http://tinyurl.com/ngbj2yk

is there something wrong with the header? I am really clueless, because on Jsfiddle all works fine even the more complex code  (probably I am just a noob ;))

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Everywhere you're currently using

```
$(element).attr("checked","checked");
```

change it to

```
$(element).prop("checked", true); // or false
```

as `element.checked` is a property, and the `prop()` method is the proper method to use, `attr()` will only change the attribute and cause the issues you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

The following jQuery code should work just fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#eins').click(function(){
        $("#gruppe1").prop("checked", true);
    });

$('#zwei').click(function(){
        $("#gruppe2").prop("checked", true);
    });

$('#drei').click(function(){
        $("#gruppe3").prop("checked", true);
    });
});
```

**Resources:**

- [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)
- [`.attr()` vs `.prop()` on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)